# Making AWS API Gatway's response the lambda function response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Im trying to create a simple API gateway in which, with a POST method to a certain endpoint, a lambda function is executed.

Setting that up was easy enough, but I'm having some trouble with the request/response handling. Im sending the following request to the API Gateway (Im using python 3.7).

```
payload = {
    "data": "something",
    "data2": "sometsadas"
}

response = requests.post('https://endpoint.com/test', params = payload)
```

That endpoint activates a lambda function when accesed. That function just returns the same event it received.

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    return event
```

How can I make it so the `return` value of my lambda function is actually the response from the request? (Or at least a way in which the `return` value can be found somewhere inside the response)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it was a problem with how the information is sent, json format is required. Solved it by doing the following in the code.

```
payload{'data': 'someData'}
config_response = requests.post(endpointURL, data = json.dumps(config_payload))
```